# Laravel not returning a page

Tags: ajax, laravel, axios

I am saving data into database by passing variable throught ajax and using it in the controller.

Saving works fine, it saves data into a database but the problem is displaying saved page. Database has 2 fields, name and html. Name is obviously name of the website and html is pure html code. so when user saves page with name 'random' I want to display html page to him using localhost/random

Error message I get is:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fyproject\resources\views\layouts\website.blade.php)

Here's what I have done so far:

Ajax:

```
var web_name;
function updateDatabase(newCode, name_website)
{
    code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    web_name = ($('#website_name').val());
    // make an ajax request to a PHP file
    // on our site that will update the database
    // pass in our lat/lng as parameters
    $.post('http://localhost/template', {
            _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
            newCode: (code2),
            name_website: (web_name),
        })
        .done(function() {
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
     public function postDB(Request $request) {
        $newName = $request->input('name_website');
        $newLat = $request->input('newCode');
        $websites = new Website();
        $websites->name = $newName;
        $websites->html = $newLat;
        $websites->save();
        $name = $newName;
        return redirect($name);
    }
    public function website($name) {
    $website = Website::where('name', $name)->first()->html;

    // Render resources/views/template.blade.php or any view you want
    // and pass the data. E.g. $website, so you can access $website->html in your view.
    return view('layouts/website', compact('name'));
}
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('home', 'BuilderController@homepage');
Route::get('template', 'BuilderController@templates');
Route::post('template', 'BuilderController@postDB');
Route::get('logout', 'BuilderController@getLogout');
Route::get('/{name}', 'BuilderController@website');
```

website.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('title', 'Website Builder') @section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


{{html_entity_decode($name->html)}}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    axios.get('/localhost/name').then(
        html => document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = html     
    );
</script>
</html>
@endsection @show
```

What is going on?

Comment: redirect($name); and window.location with reload the page, do you need your HTML without reload the page? or You just need to show result once user save the data?

Comment: show result once user save the data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing variable called name to your view while you need to pass $website. furthermore you have a mistake in your Eloquent query.

Try to change the following,

```
$name->html // Change this
$website->html // to this
return view('layouts/website', compact('name')); // Change this
return view('layouts/website', compact('website')); // To this
$website = Website::where('name', $name)->first()->html; // Change this
$website = Website::where('name', $name)->first(); // To this
```

Comment: not working, and well I thought it's the whole point of axios to be able to access arrays

Comment: Still same issue :(

Comment: why you doing $website = Website::where('name', $name)->first()->html;
it should be just like that $website = Website::where('name', $name)->first();

Comment: Previous error has changed to this: I am not getting any errors now, but I am also not redirected to a new page, if I go to the page manually I [object Object] on the page and nothing else

Comment: I believe you need to check your routes, however I see that you are calling 
hard coded link in axios without any variables which will redirect to /name only while as you said above you need to be more dynamic

Comment: So what do you suggest? I want to show user the html page they have created otherwise whole website is pointless.. even if I do it manually I get [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

First instead of redirecting on postDB, you have to redirect via javascript

**Controller**

```
public function postDB(Request $request) {

    $website = new Website();
    $website->name = $request->input('name_website');
    $website->html = $request->input('newCode');
    $website->save();

    return response()->json(['url' => url($website->name)]);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.post('http://localhost/template', {
    _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
    newCode: (code2),
    name_website: (web_name),
}, function(response){
    // Redirecting to the new page here.
    window.location = response.url;
})
.done(function() {

})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function website($name) {
    $website = Website::where('name', $name)->first();
    return view('layouts/website', compact('website'));
}
```

Now you can access the html by accessing the **$website** variable like **$website->html**

Comment: I am just getting plan html code, not actually displaying the page

Comment: I dont understand? What do you mean by plan(plain?) html code?

Comment: plain html code so like the actual code that is being typed in a text editor so <div></div> etc, so the code is being displayed and it's not changed to actual boxes, colours etc